# From JS function to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm a complete novice in NodeJS and i have one task to do : transferring my js function to NodeJS.

Here is my javascript function in HTML

```
compressGS1DigitalLink(digitalLinkURI,useShortText,uriStem,uncompressedPrimary,useOptimisations,compressOtherKeyValuePairs) {
            // extract query string
            let firstQuestionMark = digitalLinkURI.indexOf("?");
            let queryString="";
            let nonGS1keyvaluePairs={};
            if (firstQuestionMark > -1) {
                    queryString = digitalLinkURI.substr(1+firstQuestionMark);
            }
            if (queryString !== "") {
                    // if semicolon was used as delimiter between key=value pairs, replace with ampersand as delimiter
                    queryString = queryString.replace(new RegExp(";", 'g'),"&");

                    let firstFragment = queryString.indexOf("#");
                    if (firstFragment > -1) {
                            queryString = queryString.substring(0,firstFragment);
                    }

                    let pairs = queryString.split("&");
                    for (let i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
                            let p = pairs[i].split("=");
                            // if the key is not numeric AND is not a shortcode such as exp or expdt, then add to the nonGS1keyvalueePairs
                            if ((p[0] !== null) && (p[1] !== null) && (!(this.regexAllNum.test(p[0])) && (!(this.shortCodeToNumeric.hasOwnProperty(p[0]))))) {
                                    nonGS1keyvaluePairs[p[0]]=this.percentDecode(p[1]);
                            }
                    }
            }

            let gs1AIarray=this.extractFromGS1digitalLink(digitalLinkURI).GS1;
            let compressedDL=this.buildCompressedGS1digitalLink(gs1AIarray,useShortText,uriStem,useOptimisations,compressOtherKeyValuePairs,nonGS1keyvaluePairs);
            return compressedDL;
    }
```

And the second one :

```
    compressedDigitalLinkOutput : function() {
            if (this.elementStringInput !== "") {
                try {
                    this.error1="";
                    return gs1dlt.gs1ElementStringsToCompressedGS1DigitalLink(this.elementStringInput, (this.shortnames =="true"), this.uristem, (this.uncompressedPrimary=="true") , (this.useOptimisations=="true") );
                } catch(err) {
                    this.digitalLinkOutput="";
                    this.error1=err+"\n"+err.stack;
                    return "";
                }
            } else {
            return "";
            }
        },
```

And what i need to do is remove both of them from JS and have them in NodeJS.

And these functions are supposed to compress an input :

```
<tr class="digitalLink"><td class="label">Input: Uncompressed GS1 Digital Link URI</td><td>
<form action="/compression" method="get">
<input id="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" class="digitalLink" type="text" v-model="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput"></td><td class="charCount">{{uncompressedDigitalLinkInput.length}}</td>
```

Here is what i tried to do : using get and post request to pass the parameters

```
  app.post('/compression', function(req,res){
  if (this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput !== "") {
    try {
      this.error3="";
      return gs1dlt.compressGS1DigitalLink(this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput,(this.shortnames =="true"),this.uristem,(this.uncompressedPrimary=="true"),(this.useOptimisations=="true"),(this.compressOtherKeyValuePairs=="true"));
    } catch(err) {
      this.error3=err+"\n"+err.stack;
      return "";
    }


  } else {
    return "";
  }
  return uncompressedDigitalLinkInput;
})
```

The supposed output should be this 
[image]

This is what i got for the moment :
[image]
And i don't understand why it is not working, with the NodeJS function, i pass the parameters and return the appropriate variable.
So what can i do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Express.js.

If you want to send a response to the client, you should use **send** method on the Response object rather than return something.

Try something like this

```
 app.post('/compression', function(req,res){
  if (this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput !== "") {
    try {
      this.error3="";
      const response = gs1dlt.compressGS1DigitalLink(this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput,(this.shortnames =="true"),this.uristem,(this.uncompressedPrimary=="true"),(this.useOptimisations=="true"),(this.compressOtherKeyValuePairs=="true"));
      res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch(err) {
      this.error3=err+"\n"+err.stack;
      res.status(200).send("");
    }


  } else {
    res.status(200).send("");
  }
  res.status(200).send(uncompressedDigitalLinkInput);
})
```

Comment: Hey @vrdrv, 
Thank you for your response, i Just tried it and it still doesn't show the output.

Maybe we need to work with the first function too : compressGS1DigitalLink ?

Comment: Well, I don't know how exactly you fill all the variables like "this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput", just wanted to make clear that returning something will not send anything to the client. Can you provide the whole code? I suspect that "this.uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" is always undefined since "this" refers to the enclosing function.

Comment: Yes here it is :